# Using MAX function for time in where condtion

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Hi I have table where new rows get inserted every 5 seconds.
Below is the query i am using to get the latest record of each Index ID with max index_end_time.

[image]

Now I need to check if there are any records whose MAX(INDEX_END_TIME) is elapsed more than 5 minutes than the current system time stamp.

some thing like below

```
SELECT  count(INDEX_ID) 
  FROM PS8BPMDB.BPM_TASK_INDEX_JOB 
  GROUP BY INDEX_ID 
  HAVING   MAX(INDEX_END_TIME) > SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(SYSTIMESTAMP)UTC_SYS - 5 minutes;
```

Comment: You tagged both oracle and mysql. Your screenshot suggests this is oracle. mysql is another database. Please update your tags correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do calculations on a column of data type `TIMESTAMP` you need to use the `INTERVAL` datatype.

```
SELECT count(INDEX_ID) 
  FROM PS8BPMDB.BPM_TASK_INDEX_JOB 
  GROUP BY INDEX_ID 
HAVING MAX(INDEX_END_TIME) > systimestamp - interval '5' minute;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another query.. I wanted to check if latest record's index_end_time elapsed more than 5 minutes..

```
select count(*) from (SELECT MAX(INDEX_END_TIME) as max_end_time,  INDEX_ID as idx_id FROM PS8BPMDB.BPM_TASK_INDEX_JOB GROUP BY INDEX_ID)
where max_end_time < SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(SYSTIMESTAMP)- interval '5' minute;
```

Comment: Please don't post additional questions as answers to an existing question. They are not visible to the community (I accidentally saw it). The goal is that other members benefit from your question and it's answers and embedded questions make that impossible.